# Retrieving data from Parse - NullPoint Exception

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have created a profile creation page, where after completion, information such as age, name, gender, search distance are stored into parse. Now that I have the information, retrieving it is where I am experiencing issues. In particular, I have been only able to retrieve the objectID successfully. In the sense that the list only populates list users by their objectID. I have tried to populated using their names instead, with other information such as "Headline", "Age", and "ProfilePicture".

"Name", "Age", "Headline" are strings, where the users have already recorded their information in their profile creation.

"ProfilePicture" is a file, where users have uploaded their picture, which was converted and stored into parse as a file.

**Update:**
NullPoint Exception

```
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 8886
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at com.dooba.beta.ProfileCreation$1.onClick(ProfileCreation.java:144)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-14 19:06:09.375: E/AndroidRuntime(8886):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 19:06:11.507: I/Process(8886): Sending signal. PID: 8886 SIG: 9
08-14 19:06:11.995: D/dalvikvm(8946): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 192K, 8% free 2928K/3176K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
```

@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.matching);

```
        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        setConversationsList();
    }
    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
      // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

           ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

         //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

           query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
           // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
           query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
           // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
           query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
           query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
           query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Minimum_Age", minimumAge);
           query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Maximum_Age", maximumAge);
    //     query.whereWithinKilometers("Maximum_Distance", point, maxDistance)





        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());


                    }

                    usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                    namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
           public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
               if (e == null) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                   startActivity(intent);
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Error finding that user",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your support, and kindly advise.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here - what exactly are you trying to do? and why is the code you posted not achieving that for you?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Allow me to clarify myself. I have been able to retrieve a list of users listed by their ObjectID (objectId is a column in a parse that associates users with a code). Instead I want to retrieve their name, and other information such as headline etc. These information have been recorded when the users where completing their profile creation page. Hence, I want to replace ObjectID with Name, and retrieve additional information.

Comment: I think you want to be using getter methods with keys, like userList.get(i).getString("Name"), .getString("Headline"), and .getInt("Age") if Age is a Number.  does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It has answered my questions, however, when putting it into action I encountered an unexpected nullpoint exception error. The strings items are displayed, but when they are clicked (was suppose to lead to an instant messaging page), an unexpected error occur. This error did not appear when I was using ObjectID, so I am not too sure where the issue lies. I have updated the code under the update section of my initial post, and have included the logcat message. If you could asssist me with that than that would be incredibly helpful. Thanks

Comment: from the line numbers in your code, can you tell me which line is causing the exception?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I believe the issue starts from  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e). In particular, it is these lines that are problematic (they display the information, but do not respond to click) names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString())..."Headline"..."Age"; Previously it was                          names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
Thanks

Comment: Hmm - try moving the line "usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);" out of the done method and up into your onCreate method - then right underneath, do usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(getApplicationContext());  then implement the onItemClick method somewhere that is outside all other methods